# How to call onchange event on scope value, without usign directive in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a dynamic form, in this form I want to make onchange operations in some elements.

I am trying to do it by jquery. as `$('element-id').change...`

```
.controller("autoQuoteCtrl", ["$log", "$scope", "$rootScope", "dtoResource", "$http", "$state", "$stateParams", "postDtoFactory", function ($log, $scope, $rootScope, dtoResource, $http, $state, $stateParams, postDtoFactory) {
                    $scope.answers.PC.change = function() {
                        console.log('here');
                    };
                }]);
```

If I change answers.PC value my action should get execute.

I am not sure how it will work but looking around to achieve such solution, where I could achieve this without making change in html.

https://plnkr.co/edit/GA74YHNFxFb0ARg16Sjj?p=preview
In `controldirective.js` file function(directive) `textControlDir()` added `ng-change="my-{{queObj._attributeName}}"`

This creates ng-change="myPC"

In autoQuoteCtrl.js 
added

```
 $scope.answers.myPC = function() {
                        console.log('here');
                    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#element-id').change(function(e){
var currentElement = document.getElementById("element-id");
//or use **this** which also points to the same element.
//var currentElement = this;
var currentElementScope = angular.element(currentElement).scope();
//call the change function explictly
currentElementScope.answers.PC.change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = { name: 'World' };
  $scope.name = "Felipe";
  $scope.$watch('name',function(o,n){
    console.log(o)
  })
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myDirectiveVar: '=',
     //bindAttr: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="some">' +
      '<input ng-model="myDirectiveVar"></div>',
    replace: true,
    //require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      console.debug($scope);
      //var textField = $('input', elem).attr('ng-model', 'myDirectiveVar');
      // $compile(textField)($scope.$parent);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-directive my-directive-var="name"></my-directive>{{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

You can use `ng-change` or `$scope.$watch` for detecting any changes

```
$scope.$watch('answers.PC.change', function(oldvalue, newvalue) {
  console.log('here');
});
```

or

`ng-change="yourFunctionWillRunOnChanges()"`

Comment: you are using directive so i took this example to get what you want i hope this help :-)